# Labeling cities with GeoGraphics

Tags: geographics

I have the picture below

[image]and I am struggling to put the respective labels on the three cities (namely Shenzhen, Dongying and Zhangye) from which the colored edges come out.

I am using this code

'''

```
Show[
 GeoGraphics[{
   Polygon[Entity["Country", "China"]],
   OptimalOpenFacilities,
   GeoMarker[OptimalOpenFacilities, OpenFacilities, 
    "Alignment" -> Bottom, "Scale" -> Offset[1000], "Color" -> White]
   },
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders", "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6], 
  "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3], "Border" -> Black}, GeoZoomLevel -> 4]],
 ImageSize -> {1600, 975}
 ]
```

'''
where OptimalOpenFacilities and OpenFacilities are the Entities and the names, respectively, of the three cities considered.

Do you have any idea of how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add in the `InputForm` definitions of `OptimalOpenFacilities` and `OpenFacilities` to this post?

Comment: sure!

CityList = CityData[{Large, "China"}];
OptimalOpenFacilities = 
  Select[CityList, 
   QuantityMagnitude[CityData[#, "Population"]] >= 1000000 && 
     QuantityMagnitude[CityData[#, "Population"]] <= 15000000 &];
OpenFacilities = #1 & @@@ 
   Transpose[{CommonName@OptimalOpenFacilities}];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that you were specifying the marker as a list of titles, so the code was literally telling Mathematica that the map marker for each location should be the entire list. Below, I've Mapped your data such that each location now has it's own GeoMarker that looks like: `GeoMarker[Entity, Name, Options]`

```
Show[
 GeoGraphics[{
   Polygon[Entity["Country", "China"]],
   OptimalOpenFacilities,
   Map[GeoMarker[#[[1]], #[[2]], "Alignment" -> Bottom, 
      "Scale" -> Offset[1000], "Color" -> White] &, 
    Transpose[{OptimalOpenFacilities, OpenFacilities}]]
   },
  GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"CountryBorders",
     "Land" -> GrayLevel[0.6],
     "Ocean" -> GrayLevel[0.3],
     "Border" -> Black}
    , GeoZoomLevel -> 4]],
 ImageSize -> {1600, 975}
 ]
```

Does this match what you were trying to accomplish?
[image]